# Inserting data into multiple tables using one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

i am new to ruby on rails...
i'm making a project on office space rent
each listing has many images
there's a listing table and images table

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :agent_id, :description, :key_feature, :location_id, :size, :title,    :office_type, :parking_ratio, :floors, :price, :nearest_metro, :distance, :image, :location_title, :display_order, :images_attributes

 has_many:images, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end



class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 # attr_accessible :title, :body
 attr_accessible :id, :image_url, :title_image, :listing_id, :created_at, :updated_at
 belongs_to :listing
end
```

I want to make form for listings so that it also asks for adding images for that particular listing.It should make a blank tab for image_url and upload small image of it to its right.And below it should ask for add new image... clicking that renders another image_url tab and so on...
Listing should be saved in listings table and images should be saved in images table refering that listing..Please help me!!!
I've made form using following code :-

```
<%=f.fields_for :images do |image| %>
 <%= image.label :image %><br />
 <%= image.text_field :image_url %><br /> <br />
 <%= image.hidden_field :listing_id, :value => params[:id] %>
```

It would show images already manually inserted in DB for listings and thereby, showing them when editing a particular listing.But when asking for making a new listing,it never shows image tab... So m helpless..I suspect whole structure might be wrong.. Please help me!

And here's my listing controller for update and create

```
def create
@listing = Listing.new(params[:listing])


respond_to do |format|
  if @listing.save
    format.html { redirect_to ([:member, @listing]), notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @listing, status: :created, location: @listing }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
def update
@listing = Listing.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if (@listing.update_attributes(params[:listing]))
    format.html { redirect_to ([:member, @listing]), notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: You must check http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2. It will guide you the best way i have ever seen :)